# Changing status bar position to correct position

Tags: iphone

see below image, status bar showing at some below level on simulator. it works fine on device.
why this happenes? anyone has any idea?  because of this i can't guess correct positions of other controls.

why this happens? and any way to correct this?

already i have added retina support images. generally it shows blank space on below area if retina images are not available . but i am seeing this first time that status bar is showing at some below level

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image] click on warning and select Add

Comment: i have already added images but just clicking on add it works fine.

Comment: here warning shows missing images but already i have added images with correct naming. & only clicking on add works all fine

Answer (score 0):

you have to support iPhone5 resolution.
add a splash screen naming Default-568h.png of resolution 1136x640. 
If you run this on iPhones having 3.5 inch screen it will be working fine.