# In iPhone 4inch screen, it shows up 3.5inch screen in simulator. Please checkout the screen shot. What may be the issue?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, user-interface

[image: Simulator screenshot]

In iPhone 4inch screen it shows up 3.5inch screen in simulator. Please checkout the above screen shot. What may be the issue? or what I have missed out?

Comment: where's your screenshot ??

Comment: Missing `Default-568h@2x.png`, its required to enable 4 inch screen layout.

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya Sorry! Please check now..

Comment: @JimBozZ check my answer. first go in your warning section you show Ratina 4 Support Warning click on that and add image automatically. full info is in my answer.

Comment: @JimBozZ problem solve now  ??

Comment: Check my answer. i hope help you...........

[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336252/changing-status-bar-position-to-correct-position/17336551#17336551

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya Ya solved, Thanks..!

Comment: @JimBozZ welcome bro.if any problem anytime .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First Show this image . in that image you show warning for Retina 4 support so click on this warning and click on add so your retina 4 splash screen automatic add in your project.

[image: Show image here]

and after you use this code :

```
if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
    {
        // For iphone 5
    }
    else
    {
        // For iphone 4 or less
    }
```