# Black bars simulating iPhone 5 - Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

When running the iPhone 5 simulator 2 black bars appear making it the resolution of the iPhone 4(s). My question is: how am I able to use the full screen resolution? (it also creates black bars all around the app when trying to simulate an iPad)

Now, I know this questions has been answered multiple times here on stackoverflow, but all of them give the solution of adding a Default-568h@2x.png launch image. I want to make use of the LaunchScreen.xib instead of creating all the seperate launch screen images.

Anyone got a solution for this?

Thanks!
- Merijn

Comment: can you add screen shot

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1

Comment: @Sport http://s17.postimg.org/herxese1r/Schermafbeelding_2015_04_01_om_15_51_57.png when pressing the home button the black area is a useable part of the iphone

Comment: @MerijnDenHouting you must need to add lauchscreen for support iphone5. check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803217/in-iphone-4inch-screen-it-shows-up-3-5inch-screen-in-simulator-please-checkout/23803282#23803282

Answer (score 2):

You must use a specific launch image to take into account the 4" inches screens... 
or either way you can use a specific Launch screen with autolayout constraint for example if you don't want to add too many launch images : http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/12/24/using-a-launch-screen-storyboard.html